# Why do I receive [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host" when running yum commands in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS?

Tags: centos, yum, update, rhel6, subscription

When running `yum update`, the below error message occurs

> Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security
>   redhat-rhn-satellite-5.5-server-x86_64-6                                                                                         | 1.6 kB     00:00
>   https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/6/6Server/x86_64/cf-tools/1/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
>   Trying other mirror.
>   https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/6/6Server/x86_64/rhev-agent/3/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
>   Trying other mirror.
>   https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/6/6Server/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
>   Trying other mirror.
>   Error: failed to retrieve repodata/e847e0e8ad4903bd2acbbeea4eb487dbd3af3061a40b5a7f074f9e60709d49b7-updateinfo.xml.gz from redhat-rhn-satellite-5.5-server-x86_64-6
>   error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"

Yum fails with error

> Error: failed to retrieve repodata/c964d1bced53b5fb02369d8429e2d2cd5a8699c6bab094b473f9e830afaa75a7-primary.xml.gz from rhel-x86_64-server-6
>   error was [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"

Comment: @fvu That's not what the error message says. It says `Trying other mirror` which implies it's already doing that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir TMP
cd TMP`

downloaded files below from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

> centos-indexhtml-6-2.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
>   python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-11.el6.noarch.rpm
>   yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm
>
> centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.x86_64.rpm
>   yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
>   yum-plugin-keys-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm

```
rpm -e --nodeps redhat-release redhat-indexhtml
yum remove rhnlib abrt-plugin-bugzilla redhat-release-notes*
yum remove subscription-manager
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/*
rpm -Uvh *.rpm
yum clean all
yum update
```

Reference: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide